# Using Context Menu On Fancybox Image Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu, fancybox

I integrated this right click context menu into my website: http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/#download

my problem now is when I use fancybox to show an image, I can't seem to find a selector to target so i can use my custom context menu when i right click on the fancybox image popup.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found the answer.

in the fancybox options, use the onComplete callback

onComplete : function() {
                           $("selector").contextMenu({
                              blah
                           });
                        }